# RStats particular key combination in Karabiner

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

I'd like to edit this

```
<!-- change left command to control, send command+space when left command is pressed twice. -->
<autogen>
  __DoublePressModifier__
  KeyCode::COMMAND_L,
  KeyCode::CONTROL_L,
  KeyCode::SPACE, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L,
</autogen>
```

so that I can obtain `%>%` when pressing `BACKQUOTE` twice. I cannot succeed with that key.

Ideas?

Many thank thanks in advice !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet will work:

```
<item>
<name>Double press Backquote to %>% in RStats</name>
<identifier>backquote2%>%</identifier>
<only>RSTATS</only>
  <autogen>
  __DoublePressModifier__
  KeyCode::BACKQUOTE,
  KeyCode::BACKQUOTE,
  KeyCode::DELETE, KeyCode::DELETE, KeyCode::KEY_5, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L, KeyCode::DOT, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L, KeyCode::KEY_5, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L
  </autogen>
</item>
```

You have to add RStats' app bundle identifier - available in Karabiner's Event Viewer > Apps - to `/Applications/Karabiner.app/Contents/Resources/appdef.xml`.

A single backquote gives a backquote, two backquotes entered fast enough `%>%`. I think a more elegant version exists - I haven't found it yet though.